# Error querying parquet files with Apache-Drill : Error in parquet record reader

Tags: parquet, apache-drill

I need to use parquet files in order to do some analysis and enrich them with information. However, I am cannot do anything because of incompatible column datatypes (unsigned integers).

I tried to use Apache-drill but the same error occurs when I want to execute some queries.

Here is the query I want to use to begin with and the error message : `SELECT * from dfs.'/home/artyom/addresses.parquet' LIMIT 5;`

```
Error: INTERNAL_ERROR ERROR: Error in parquet record reader.
Message: 
Hadoop path: /home/artyom/addresses.parquet/part.0.parquet
Total records read: 0
Row group index: 0
Records in row group: 34369585
Parquet Metadata: ParquetMetaData{FileMetaData{schema: message schema
{
  optional binary ip (UTF8);
  optional int64 ip_id (UINT_64);
  optional int32 reputation (UINT_8);
  optional int32 confidence (UINT_8);
  optional float queries_ratio;
(...)
}
```

But queries like : `SELECT ip from dfs.'/home/artyom/addresses.parquet' LIMIT 5;` or `SELECT queries_ratio from dfs.'/home/artyom/addresses.parquet' LIMIT 5;` work like a charm.
Only the unsigned integers columns are a problem.

I read the apache-drill documentation about converting datatypes and tried several things but without success.

Could someone help me with this and tell me if there is a way to convert the UINT_X into compatible INTEGER types ? The conversion from unsigned integer to interger will not be a problem for the data.
I just need to find out how to modify the column datatypes of the parquet file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify, which version of Drill you are using? Looks like the issue with reading UINT type was fixed in the scope of [DRILL-4764](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4764) and [DRILL-5971](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-5971).

So it should work on Drill 1.14 and later.

Comment: I am using version 1.16.0 which is the last version available as I speak. I think the fixes DRILL-4764 and DRILL-597 you mentioned concern signed integers and not unsigned ones. In the comments regarding the issues, people attached files with UINT in order to show that they are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that you are using the latest version. 
I tried reading parquet files attached to the DRILL-4764, and Drill is able to read them without issues.
Could you please share sample file for which query fails into the DRILL-5983.

Comment: It is I who tank you. It is a good news but this makes my problem even stranger. I am afraid I cannot share the file because it is far too heavy and it might contain information I am not allowed to share. I could create a sample file from it but I do not not know how to do that with Parquet files even if I have already tried many times.

Comment: You may try to generate parquet file using java code. As an example, you may use this class: https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/8ddc9d79e0d298e74f2256328dd9ddee06a20066/exec/java-exec/src/test/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/parquet/ParquetSimpleTestFileGenerator.java#L54

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, another Parquet reader can be used: `use store.parquet.use_new_reader = true;`.
Issue for the default reader will be fixed in Drill 1.17.0 (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-5983 for details).